# They're all gonna laugh at you!

Tags: riddle, sports

There are 11 ways to get to X.
There is only one way to get to X+1.

What is X, the ways to get to X, X+1, and the way to get to X+1?

Hint:

> You'll know your answer is correct if you understand the title of this question.

Hint 2:

> X is a number.

Comment: Note: I'm not 100% sure if *riddle* is a proper tag for this. I apologize if it isn't. Unfortunately I probably won't get good advice on that until it's answered.

Comment: There are 11 ways a batter can reach base in Major League Baseball without recording a hit.

Comment: @Alexis - but I assume there is more than 1 way to get to 2nd base... (Interesting, but not it.)

Comment: @TTT There is indeed.

Comment: @TTT I think another hint may be required

Comment: all I can think about is adam sandler

Comment: My only issue with the puzzle is there are many ways to get 290 because there are many possible spares, plus throwing a gutter for your last ball.

Comment: @user1717828 - there are exactly 11 ways to get 290. I listed them in a separate answer.

Comment: Am I the only one who thought the title was in reference to the movie "Carrie"?

Comment: @TTT, I stand corrected!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

X is:

> 290

Because:

> In bowling there are 11 ways to score 290. The only way to score 291 is to almost bowl a perfect game, then mess up. 
>  Derived from http://www.balmoralsoftware.com/bowling/bowling.htm and charfellow's answer

Comment: You can use < br > (no spaces) to put line breaks in your spoilers without breaking the spoiler tag. I usually put two of those. Alternately, you can put a blank line and then some normal text and then a new spoiler tag.

Comment: @Duncan thanks for the pointers, that helped out.

Comment: Well done! In case someone missed it, the only way to get 291 is 11 strikes in a row followed by 1 pin on the last throw. I don't know if anyone has ever done that, but if so, I'm sure the title would be accurate!

Comment: Nice work, but how is this related to the title of the question like the OP says?

Comment: @Pedro To get to X+1 (i.e. 291), you need to bowl a perfect game until the very end, and then totally screw up the last throw. I don't know about you, but I'd be laughing if someone I was with did that.

Comment: @cpast not nearly as bad, but the night my dad earned is 300 ring he didn't break 700. He took a lot of sh... grief... for that for years hahaha.

Answer (score 7):

> X=Getting out in Cricket:
>   There are 11 ways to get out in cricket. See http://sportzwiki.com/cricket/the-eleven-ways-of-getting-out-in-cricket/
>
> X+1 = Getting out twice in cricket:
>
> How to get to X+1:
>   you can be run out from a no ball if not attempting a run if ;
>
> you bat outside the crease , a no ball is delivered , you hit the ball to slips and the slip fielder throws the ball on to the stumps and you are still out side the crease this would be out run out.
>
> People would laugh at you for getting two outs in one at bat

Comment: How does the part about people laughing at you fit in?

Comment: See updated answer

Comment: That's not it, but +1 for forcing a square peg into a round hole!

Comment: @dpwilson: Isn't the fact that you're playing cricket enough reason for them to laugh at you?

Comment: @DSKekaha That's mean. It's trueness is irrelevant.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like

> x= 200560490130 , x+1=200560490131. The 11 ways to get to it are the 11 primes in its prime factorization. X+1 has only one way; since it cannot have any of those primes as factors, it must itself be prime. Not sure how the title factors in though. Could refer to the actual math folks laughing at me because I made a mistake :D

Comment: Sorry, but not it. I'm pretty sure if your answer was correct, that there would be many others like it that would also be correct.

Comment: The puzzle is tagged "sports".

Comment: Yea, because people that play sports laugh at people that do math :P

Comment: You are correct! People are laughing at you for using [tag:math]s to answer a [tag:sports] question.

Answer (score 3):

Could also be:

> getting a strike in bowling

Reasoning:

> If you have any one ball in which you don't get a strike (labeled as X), you have 11 strikes.
>  There is only one way to get 12 strikes, and get a perfect game.
>  Maybe people are laughing at you because you came so close to the perfect game.

Comment: This isn't the correct answer, but you're on the right track.

Answer (score 3):

> X=6
>
> 11 ways to get to X: There are 11 players on the football field that could all score a touchdown
>
> One way to get to x+1: The only way to get to 7 is to kick an extra point by the place kicker:
>
> Everyone is going to laugh at you: No one respects the placekicker and everyone will laugh if you miss the extra point.

Comment: Another good try, but still not it. I think last season, after they moved the extra point back, there were many more misses, and thus probably not laugh worthy.

Comment: Admittedly not likely, but 7 could also be achieved with 2 safeties and a field goal.

Answer (score 2):

X is:

> 10

Because:

> It's soring 10 in ten pin bowling.
>  You get 10 points for a strike, one way to get that, or a spare, 10 ways to get a spare. For a total of 11 ways.
>  X+1 is when you get 1 added to your 10 for subsequent rolls and you only knocked down 1 pin after a spare or throw a gutter ball and also knocked down 1 pin after a strike.  That's going to make them laugh.

Comment: This isn't the correct answer, but you're on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some additional information in case anyone is interested.

The 11 ways to get to X are:

> 0-9 pins on the first throw, followed by a spare, followed by 11 strikes. (10 total possibilities)
>
>  11 strikes followed by a gutter ball. (1 possibility)
>
>  = 11 ways to get to 290

The 1 way to get to X+1 is:

> 11 strikes followed by a horrible throw of just 1 pin = 1 way to get to 291

According to [this trivia page](http://www.topendsports.com/sport/tenpin/trivia-fewest.htm),

> Some people have bowled 291 before, in some cases due to a gross error on the last throw. I'm sure there was laughter involved!
>
>  It's much harder to get just 2 pins on a single throw (with 10 pins standing) than to get a strike, so the least likely score in a single game is probably 292. Sometimes 292 is attempted on purpose, basically for bragging rights, since it's so much harder to achieve than a perfect score of 300. (I suppose it's also probably the case that someone attempting to score 292 doesn't succeed and could end up with 291 instead.)
>
>  A score of 299.5 has happened before when on the last throw one pin broke in half and part of it remained standing.